# Move Ubuntu 22.04 to hardware hp p410i RAID1 with encrypted volumes on BIOS

Tags: partitioning, grub2, encryption, raid, luks

I have an old hp n40l microserver with Ubuntu 22.04 on board with quite old BIOS as of 2012.
Now my SSD 256GB disk is split to 2 partitions: /boot/efi and /.

I've bought hp p410i RAID card, and 3 more additional SSDs (1*256G and 2*500G) to provide redundancy, add separate disk for app data and database files, so to have 2 RAID1 arrays.

My main question is how to move the system to RAID1 array, encrypt it and make it bootable? So, if something happens with one of disks, it may be easily replaced with the new one without playing with grub etc?

One of my thoughts is to place /boot/efi to an pen drive (SD disk placed in 4G USB modem) and make it bootable. While the rest of the system to encrypt with LUKS. Will it work? Or there may be some other better ideas?